# Не отправляется сообщение с формой select

Tags: php

При заполнении select городом, кидает на страницу 404

```html
<?
if (isset ($_POST['telFF'])) {
  mail ("support@",
        "заполнена контактная форма с ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],
        "Ваш город: ".$_POST['name']."\nНазвании компании: ".$_POST['nameComp']."\nНомер телефона: ".$_POST['telFF']."\nКатегория: ".$_POST['nameFF1']."\nПоследние: ".$_POST['loginFF']);
  echo ('<p style="color: green">Ваше сообщение получено, спасибо!</p>');
}
?>
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="feedback-form">
    <label for="region_id">Выберите регион:</label><br/>
    <select name="region_id" id="region_id" class="StyleSelectBox">
        <option value="0">- выберите регион -</option>
        <option value="4312">Москва и Московская обл.</option>
        <option value="4925">Санкт-Петербург и область</option>
        <!-- ... -->
    </select>
    <br/>
    <div id="frmCheckUsername">
        <label for="name">Выберите город:</label><br/>
        <select name="name" id="name" disabled="disabled" class="StyleSelectBox" onBlur="checkAvailability()">
            <option value="0">- выберите город -</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <span id="user-availability-status"></span>    
    </div>
    <p><img src="/wp-content/themes/classipress-v3.5.1/LoaderIcon.gif" id="loaderIcon" style="display:none" /></p>
    <b>Название компании:</b>
    <input type="text" name="nameComp" required placeholder="Название Вашей компании" x-autocompletetype="name">
    <b>Категория:</b><br />
    <select name="nameFF1" x-autocompletetype="name">
        <option>Недвижимость</option>
        <option>Транспорт</option>
        <!-- ... -->
    </select><br />
    <b>Ваш номер телефона:</b>
    <input type="text" name="telFF" required placeholder="Номер телефона" x-autocompletetype="name">
    <b>Последние 4 цифры вашей квитанции:</b>
    <input type="text" name="loginFF" required placeholder="Введите цифры" x-autocompletetype="email">
    <input type="submit" value="отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: У формы не задан target.

Comment: select заполняется по средствам ajax http://webersoft.ru/select-ajax-mysql/.

Comment: Возможно что-то делается в checkAvailability()

Comment: Какой плагин используется для заполнения select?